# AWS S3 : Is there any way to count rows of uploaded file?

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-cli

We'd like to check the row count of uploaded files on AWS S3, if the uploading task is sure to be end correctly.

Now we're simply sending exported files by Windows AWS CLI command as follows, after exporting from SQL Server;

```
aws s3 cp !SEND_FILE! %S3_DIR%/
```

Kindly let us know if there is any way to check the count of uploaded files on S3 bucket.
If there is no appropriate way to count them, to get any uploading error code as altanative way would be also appreciated.

Thanks for your advice in advance.

Comment: You could use [S3 Select](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/s3-glacier-select/) to count the lines, but if your goal is to verify correct upload then using the MD5 checksum is the best approach (since number of lines doesn't guarantee the file totally matches).

Comment: Thanks a lot, @John Rotenstein. Checking MD5 should be perfect to ensure data integrity of uploaded files on AWS S3. We'll try  'aws s3api put-object' to verify MD5 (as well as AWS CLI return error capture stdunbar kindly let me know). Thank you so much for your usefule information and understanding to my goal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without re-downloading the file there isn't a way to count the lines on S3 directly.  However, this is not needed.  From the REST API [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTObjectPUT.html):

> Amazon S3 never adds partial objects; if you receive a success
>   response, Amazon S3 added the entire object to the bucket.

The primary way this is accomplished is by verifying the MD5 hash that is calculated on the client (i.e. where you're running the CLI) is the same as the object it stored.  From the same docs:

> To ensure that data is not corrupted traversing the network, use the
>   Content-MD5 header. When you use this header, Amazon S3 checks the
>   object against the provided MD5 value and, if they do not match,
>   returns an error.

The CLI will automatically calculate the MD5 hash for you and send it to S3.  So if the object (file) did not upload correctly you would get an error back in the CLI letting you know that.

Comment: Many thanks, @stdunbar. Now I understand counting row is not appropriate and checking error message by AWS CLI should be more better way for us. Thaks to all of your clear and logical explanation, we're sure to convince our customers. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

If you have CSV/JSON/Parquet files you can count rows using [S3 Select](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/s3-glacier-select-sql-reference-select.html) command.

Using Python/boto3 it looks like this:

```
sql_stmt    = """SELECT count(*) FROM s3object S"""  
req_fact =s3.select_object_content(
    Bucket  = 'my_bucket',
    Key     = 'my/path/to/file.parquet',
    ExpressionType  = 'SQL',
    Expression      = sql_stmt,
    InputSerialization={'Parquet': {}},
    OutputSerialization = {'CSV': {
                'RecordDelimiter': os.linesep,
                'FieldDelimiter': colsep}},
    
)
```

If you want to count records in all files in bucket check out this script:
[S3 line counter](https://github.com/pydemo/S3-parquet-files-row-counter/blob/main/s3_row_counter.py)

Comment: Wow, that's so wonderful, Alex !! Your advice will improve our operation.  So far we did checked it with "aws s3api put-object --bucket %S3_BUCKET% --key %DEST_FILENAME% --body %SRC_FILENAME% --metadata md5chksum=%SRC_HASH% --content-md5 %SRC_HASH%" thanks to former advice here. And now we can check the count, too. Thank you so much.