# AWS S3 : How to Get S3 Upload Result

Tags: batch-file, amazon-s3

Thanks to [the last advice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52529392/aws-s3-is-there-any-way-to-count-rows-of-uploaded-file), now we can check the integrity of S3 uploaded file by hash value in our batch;

```
:: Get the MD5 Hased Value of local target file
CALL %BAT_DIR%\GET_HASHVALUE_BASE64.bat

:: Upload File to S3 with MD5 Hash Value 
aws s3api put-object --bucket %S3_BUCKET% --key %S3_SEND_DIR%/%FILE_NAME% --body %SEND_FILE% --metadata md5chksum=%HashBase64% --content-md5 %HashBase64%

-- Hash was matched between the local and uploaded S3 file, "Etag" was returned
{ 
    "ETag": "\"63df79d4c782a0df2186dda1c601931c\"" 
}
```

If we can detect the S3 uploaded success by "Etag" return, we'd like to get it for failure detection at our batch.

So far, it doesn't work as my expectations though...

```
:: trial example
set S3_COMMAND_STR=aws s3api put-object --bucket %S3_BUCKET% --key %S3_SEND_DIR%/%FILE_NAME% --body %SEND_FILE% --metadata md5chksum=%HashBase64% --content-md5 %HashBase64%

:: Uploaded Result Get
for /F %%A in ('%S3_COMMAND_STR%') do (set S3_RESULT=%%A) 

-- Return Command Error
File aws was not found.
```

You might know any more smart way for failuer detection on S3 uploading, any advice would be grateful again.

Thank you so much.

FYI. Mightbe we'll try 'S3 select' later but now we're verifying simplest way

Comment: Pretty sure `S3` returns an errorlevel when it finishes.  You should just be able to check the %errorlevel% variable.  I can check when I get back to work tomorrow.

Comment: Oh, many thanks @Squashman. If errorlevel can make it, that would be wonderful for us! I'd be so grateful if you'll check it whenever you have a chance. Thank you so much.

Comment: You can probably check it before me. I am going to bed.  Here is the documentation. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/topic/return-codes.html

Comment: @Squashman, I really appreciated all of your kind advice. Now we can detect any S3 uploading errors. That's so wonderful.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Squashman, we could detect any s3 uploading error by error code now.

Since all uploading error returns '255', includes hash-unmatch error and backet name error and others, so far we set it each phases, so as we could easily get to know what could be root cause of the uploading error as much as possible.

```
:: S3 Bucket Tag Create
aws s3api put-object --bucket %S3_BUCKET% --key %S3_SEND_DIR%/

:: Captuer Error ==> pre-uploading check. Backet name or anything else can be wrong
if %Errorlevel% neq 0 goto ERR_S3_BACKET

:: GetHash Value (Convert from Hex to Base64)
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%h in (`CertUtil -hashfile "%SEND_FILE%" MD5 ^| find /v ":"`) do set HashHex=%%h
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%h in (`cscript //nologo HexToBase64.vbs %HashHex%`) do set HashBase64=%%h

:: Failuer to get Hash Value
if not defined HashBase64 goto ERR_GET_HASH

:: s3 File Upload and captuer error codes 
aws s3api put-object --bucket %S3_BUCKET% --key %S3_SEND_DIR%/%FILE_NAME% --body %SEND_FILE% --metadata md5chksum=%HashBase64% --content-md5 %HashBase64% 
if %Errorlevel% neq 0 goto ERR_S3_UPLOAD
```

If anyone also know how to get error details or more smarter way. 
Additional information or advice would be so much appreciated.

Thanks a lot.